# Is it possible to make changes to a list based on some condition whilst keeping the original structure of the list?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Say I have a list `[3,5,1,6,2,5,2]`. Is there a way to use list comprehension to apply changes to the list (e.g. put a 2 in front of every odd integer in the list) without changing the length of the list (i.e. `[3,25,1,26,2,25,2]`)

If I use an `if` statement in the list comprehension, I only get a subset of the list.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You want to write a function that does whatever you want (it could choose to do nothing on specific input - just return the input) and then map it on the list: `map(pad_odds, [3 ,5 ,1 , ...])`. If `pad_odds` needs the list indices as input you should look at `itertools.starmap` and `enumerate`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a list-comprehension with `if-else` to include all elements:

```
[int(f'2{x}') if i%2 else x for i, x in enumerate(lst)]
# or in a version prior to 3.6: [int('2{}'.format(x)) if i%2 else x for i, x in enumerate(lst)]
```

**Code**:

```
lst = [3,5,1,6,2,5,2]

lst = [int(f'2{x}') if i%2 else x for i, x in enumerate(lst)]
# [3, 25, 1, 26, 2, 25, 2]
```

Comment: Thanks! This worked. The `if` statement after the `for` statement works like a filter. If placed before, it becomes a conditional map (for those reading in the future).

Answer (score 0):

You should create a function to do what you need and map it on the list:

```
def pad_odds(index, value):
    if index % 2:
        return int(f'2{value}')
    return value
```

Now you can map it using the functional tools in the standard library:

```
from itertools import starmap
l = [3,5,1,6,2,5,2]
padded = list(starmap(pad_odds, enumerate(l)))
```